# Effect of a single variable in a linear model

Tags: python, linear-regression, correlation

In a multiple linear regression (MLR) model, people normally look at the relationship between each predictor and the response variable to see if it is linear. However, in my example below, I show that it can produce a totally different result from what you'll get out of a partial dependence plot. Am I right to assume that modelling the relationship between one variable and the response variable in an MLR should be avoided and we shall look at the partial independence plot to decide about the relationship?

The **correlation coefficient** also shows a negative direction, while the partial dependence plot shows a positive relationship between `X1` and `y`. Which one shall be used to decide about the relationship between each predictor and the response?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.inspection import plot_partial_dependence
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
X1 = np.array([1,2,3,7,5,4,5,9,8,7])
X2 = np.array([10,4,30,5,2,-1,0,-10,-20,-30])

y = 1*X1 + 3*X2

# Linear model using only X1
lin_model_1 = LinearRegression()
X1_df = pd.DataFrame(X1, columns=["X1"])
y_df = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=["y"])
print(y_df['y'].corr(X1_df['X1']))
lin_model_1.fit(X1_df, y)
print(lin_model_1.intercept_, lin_model_1.coef_)
y_pred_1 = lin_model_1.predict(X1_df)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.scatter(X1, y)
plt.plot(X1, y_pred_1, color='red')
plt.show()

# Multiple linear regression using both X1 and X2
X_df = pd.concat([pd.Series(X1), pd.Series(X2)], axis='columns', keys=["X1", "X2"])
lin_model = LinearRegression()
lin_model.fit(X_df, y)
print(lin_model.intercept_ , lin_model.coef_)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
ax.set_title("Linear Regression Partial Dependence")
lin_disp = plot_partial_dependence(lin_model, X_df, ['X1'], ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image: Single variable]
[image: Partial dependence]

**Update**: 
there is no strong collinearity between X1 and X2: 0.66 but the X2 and y are strongly correlated (almost 1). I haven't tried to generate another example, but I guess it's always some sort of multicollinearity between the variables that might result in such situations. Is it safe to say so?

Comment: Can you actually show the plots?

Comment: @SeanOwen, please see the update. `X1` and `X2` have collinearity and that might be the problem, but I never considered anything less that `0.8` a serious problem, so what do you think?

Comment: I guess the main reason is that X2 has a perfect correlation with y. Trying to see if the same situation happens if that is not the case

Comment: See also, e.g., https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/1580/232706 , https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3549/232706